# Extracting intersection areas in R

Tags: shapefile, polygon, r, intersection, rgdal

I have two polygons. One contains fields(X,Y,Z) and the other contains soil types (A,B,C,D). I want to know what  area of every field contains which type of soil. I tried the following:

[image]

```
library(rgdal)
library(rgeos)
Field<-readOGR("./","Field")
Soil<-readOGR("./","Soil")
Results<-gIntersects(Soil,Field,byid=TRUE)
rownames(Results)<-Field@data$FieldName
colnames(Results)<-Soil@data$SoilType

> Results
      A     B     C     D
Z  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
Y FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
X  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

and achieved good results with it telling me which field contains which soil type. However, how do I get the area instead?

Comment: As a note, st_intersection won't work if your points are latitude and longitudes. You didn't specify that you had geographic coordinates, though it's hinted at since you are talking about soil types.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This method uses the `intersect()` function from the `raster` package. The example data I've used aren't ideal (for one thing they're in unprojected coordinates), but I think it gets the idea across.

```
library(sp)
library(raster)
library(rgdal)
library(rgeos)
library(maptools)

# Example data from raster package
p1 <- shapefile(system.file("external/lux.shp", package="raster"))
# Remove attribute data
p1 <- as(p1, 'SpatialPolygons')
# Add in some fake soil type data
soil <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(p1, data.frame(soil=LETTERS[1:12]), match.ID=F)

# Field polygons
p2 <- union(as(extent(6, 6.4, 49.75, 50), 'SpatialPolygons'),
             as(extent(5.8, 6.2, 49.5, 49.7), 'SpatialPolygons'))
field <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(p2, data.frame(field=c('x','y')), match.ID=F)
projection(field) <- projection(soil)

# intersect from raster package
pi <- intersect(soil, field)
plot(soil, axes=T); plot(field, add=T); plot(pi, add=T, col='red')

# Extract areas from polygon objects then attach as attribute
pi$area <- area(pi) / 1000000

# For each field, get area per soil type
aggregate(area~field + soil, data=pi, FUN=sum)
```

[image: Imgur]

Results:

```
    field soil         area
1      x    A 2.457226e+01
2      x    B 2.095659e+02
3      x    C 5.714943e+00
4      y    C 5.311882e-03
5      x    D 7.620041e+01
6      x    E 3.101547e+01
7      x    F 1.019455e+02
8      x    H 7.106824e-03
9      y    H 2.973232e+00
10     y    I 1.752702e+02
11     y    J 1.886562e+02
12     y    K 1.538229e+02
13     x    L 1.321748e+02
14     y    L 1.182670e+01
```

Comment: To clarify: I prefer `raster::intersect` over `rgeos::gIntersection` because the former joins the attribute data from the two `SpatialPolgonsDataFrame` objects, while the latter seems to drop the attribute data.

Comment: Thanks for the many details and the correct answer. You helped me a lot!!!

Comment: If you use byid=TRUE in "gIntersection" it will return attribute IDS which can be used with merge to associate the attributes. The functions are different and it should be noted how. The "intersect" function uses the overlapping extents whereas, "gIntersection" is the explicit intersection of the vector geometries. The intersect approach is a square/rectangular intersection and not an intersection of the actual polygons. The extent can be redefined using extent and bbox. There are advantages to both approaches.

Comment: @JeffreyEvans Good point re `gIntersection`; however, the input feature IDs aren't directly provided, they're concatenated and stored in the feature ID of the output. This means the extra steps of parsing the IDs, then joining in the attributes. I do wish `raster::intersect` included these input IDs as additional attributes in the output.

Comment: @JeffreyEvans Also, perhaps my interpretation of your comments re `raster::intersect` is incorrect; however, I disagree that it only uses overlapping extents. In fact, it does the true intersection of the vector geometries just as `gIntersection`.

Comment: @Matt SM, from the raster intersect help "Extent objects: Returns the intersection, i.e. the area of overlap of two Extent objects" and "SpatialPolygons* objects: Only the overlapping areas (if any) are returned". I also looked at the source and it is using the extent class object to define the spatial subset.

Comment: @JeffreyEvans Again, maybe I'm misunderstanding, but `getMethod(intersect, c("SpatialPolygons", "SpatialPolygons")) ` seems contrary to what you're saying. Also, continuing from the example in my answer above, the two methods return same geometry, only difference is attributes: `pi <- intersect(soil, field); plot(pi); pg <- gIntersection(soil, field, byid=T); plot(pg)`

Comment: I see what you're saying re the source code, `intersect.R` uses extents only, but `intersect_sp.R` uses the full geometry.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I completely missed intersect_sp. Interestingly, it uses gIntersects. Nice short cut if you want the attributes joined.

Comment: This code works fine without loading the maptools library (explicitly), at least on my system.

Answer (score 37):

Here's an alternate approach using the new `sf` package, which is meant to replace `sp`. Everything is much cleaner, and pipe friendly:

```
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)

# example data from raster package
soil <- st_read(system.file("external/lux.shp", package="raster")) %>% 
  # add in some fake soil type data
  mutate(soil = LETTERS[c(1:6,1:6)]) %>% 
  select(soil)

# field polygons
field <- c("POLYGON((6 49.75,6 50,6.4 50,6.4 49.75,6 49.75))",
        "POLYGON((5.8 49.5,5.8 49.7,6.2 49.7,6.2 49.5,5.8 49.5))") %>% 
  st_as_sfc(crs = st_crs(soil)) %>% 
  st_sf(field = c('x','y'), geoms = ., stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# intersect - note that sf is intelligent with attribute data!
pi <- st_intersection(soil, field)
plot(soil$geometry, axes = TRUE)
plot(field$geoms, add = TRUE)
plot(pi$geometry, add = TRUE, col = 'red')

# add in areas in m2
attArea <- pi %>% 
  mutate(area = st_area(.) %>% as.numeric())

# for each field, get area per soil type
attArea %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  group_by(field, soil) %>% 
  summarize(area = sum(area))
```

[image]

```
   field  soil      area
   <chr> <chr>     <dbl>
1      x     A  24572264
2      x     B 209573036
3      x     C   5714943
4      x     D  76200409
5      x     E  31015469
6      x     F 234120314
7      y     B   2973232
8      y     C 175275520
9      y     D 188656204
10     y     E 153822938
11     y     F  11826698
```