# Error "no method for coercing this S4 class to a vector"

Tags: raster, r, intersection

I am trying to reproduce the example posted on

[Extracting intersection areas in R](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/140504/extracting-intersection-areas-in-r)

Although, when I try to create the SpatialPolygon "p2", R returns the error:
"Error in as.vector(x) : no method for coercing this S4 class to a vector".

Any suggestions why is it happening? How can I fix it?

Comment: The exampled worked perfectly for me. I suggest checking that all the needed libraries in the example were loaded without any problem!

Answer (score 10):

The intersect function is masked.  Try `raster::intersect()` instead of `intersect()`.