# Obtain percentage of overlap with another multipolygon in R

Tags: raster, r, polygon, geometry, sf

I have two MULTYPOLYGONS, one where a row is a election district*year pair, and the other is a collection of flood events.

```
 district.df
      year ward_ons     cycle                       geometry
    1 2007       E1   NA-2007 POLYGON ((527370.8 183470.7...
    2 2008       E1 2007-2008 POLYGON ((528891.1 182192.6...
    3 2009       E2   NA-2009 POLYGON ((370294.2 414678.7...
    4 2010       E3   NA-2010 POLYGON ((375025.4 414992.1...
    5 2011       E3 2010-2011 POLYGON ((375150.8 410809.8...
    6 2018       E3 2011-2018 POLYGON ((373286.3 414364.5...
    7 2007       E4   NA-2007 POLYGON ((373168.6 411597.8...
    8 2010       E4 2007-2010 POLYGON ((374783.2 406209.4...
```

Flood data:

```
    flood.df
    Simple feature collection with 8 features and 2 fields
geometry type:  GEOMETRY
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: 317656.2 ymin: 90783.2 xmax: 546460.6 ymax: 631125.7
projected CRS:  OSGB 1936 / British National Grid
  year            name                       geometry
1 2007      River 2007 POLYGON ((359637.7 268239.7...
2 2007       Tank 2007 POLYGON ((325444.1 92717.57...
3 2008  Yorkshire 2008 POLYGON ((318550.7 103058.8...
4 2009 Flood East 2009 POLYGON ((541472.6 112593, ...
5 2010  Occurence 2010 MULTIPOLYGON (((545863.4 11...
6 2012      Storm 2012 POLYGON ((473637.4 103927, ...
7 2011      Flood 2011 MULTIPOLYGON (((524617.6 42...
8 2017      River 2017 POLYGON ((393387.6 631125.7...
```

What I am trying to do is to get a column in the election district multypolygon which is the share of its area that overlaps with *any* of the polygons in the flood multipolygon with the same value for `year`.

This is what I tried (influenced by [Extracting intersection areas in R](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/140504/extracting-intersection-areas-in-r))

```
# Create function
overlap.fraction <- function(election, flood, yeari){
  flood.year <- flood[flood$year == yeari,]
  election.year <- election[election$year == yeari, ]
for (i in 1:nrow(election.year)){
  int.i <- as_tibble(st_intersection(i, flood.year))
  int.i$affected <- st_area(int.i$geoms)
  affected.by.county(paste0(yeari)) <- int.i%>%
  dplyr::group_by(code) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(affected.area = sum(affected))
}
}
```

And then tried it

```
i.1990 <- overlap.fraction(district.df, flood.df, yeari = 1990)
```

But keep getting:

```
Error in UseMethod("st_intersection") : no applicable method for 'st_intersection' applied to an object of class "c('integer', 'numeric')"
```

I tried different alterations to the function and the loop inside it. Ideally, I would even get a function or loop that would do it at once instead of having to do it for every year, as is the case for what I am trying here. I am doing it this way because I am getting closer to getting it done this way, but I understand this is not the most effective way.

Answer (score 1):

At this point:

```
st_intersection(i, flood.year)
```

`i` is a number (your loop index). So its trying to do `st_intersection( 1, flood.year)` and telling you it doesn't know how to intersect a number with some polygons.

I guess you need to subset one of your spatial data objects using that index and intersect that.

Comment: I understand the issue, but I'm not sure I understand your proposed solution: Are you suggesting I should subset the multipolygon for each row? That would not be very practical as I have over 5000 rows in the original multipolygon.